# Counting visible list items and then applying class to nth item of that list in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, css-selectors

I know I can count the number of 'visible' list items like this:

```
var numOfVisibleDevices = $('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li:visible').length;
```

And I know I can target the nth item (I have to support IE8 so can't just use CSS3) by using this:

```
$('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li.span6:nth-child(2n + 3)').addClass('span-left');
$('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li.span4:nth-child(3n + 4)').addClass('span-left');
$('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li.span3:nth-child(4n + 5)').addClass('span-left');
```

But what I don't know is how to combine the two things, so I count the visible number of items in the list, and then apply the 'span-left' class to the nth child of the visible ones.

---

Because I'm using Bootstrap, span6 items will fit 2 on a line, span4 will fit 3, span3 will fit 4.
As such, I'm adding the class so that I can clear the float of the 3rd item (for span6), the 4th item (for span4) and the 5th item (for span3).  The reason for this is that each list item can vary in height, but I don't want a min height set on them.  This way, whenever the list wraps on the next line, that first item of the next line will clear the floats and the layout is always nice.

HTML is just a list:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span4">Some content</li>
        <li class="span4">Some content</li>
        <li class="span4">Some content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the html and the desired output also

Comment: what is the value of `n` in the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.each` to iterate over the elements and then apply the logic.

```
var $elems = $('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li:visible');

$elems.each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     if($this.hasClass('span3')) {
         $this.filter(':nth-child(4n + 5)').addClass('span-left');
     }
     else if($this.hasClass('span4')) {
         $this.filter(':nth-child(3n + 4)').addClass('span-left');
     }
     else if($this.hasClass('span6')) {
         $this.filter(':nth-child(2n + 3)').addClass('span-left');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the UL list items which are visible

Check jQuery `each()` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li:visible').each(function(e) {
    $('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li.span6:nth-child(2n + 3)').addClass('span-left');
    // note sure what exactly you need to do here but basically this will iterate through all visible li items of your ul
});
```

Comment: This applies the span-left class, but it doesn't seem to ignore the items with display: none.  [There's a fiddle here]: (http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/kuSnA/) and you can see if you inspect the element that the class is on the 4th item, counting the 1st hidden item.

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
var visibleDevices = $('.row-fluid ul.thumbnails li:visible');
var numOfVisibleDevices = visibleDevices.length;

visibleDevices.eq(2n + 3).addClass('span-left');
```